# From text to images in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, image, gd

Please take look the demo site at

http://jsfiddle.net/Alidad/fexGj/

That demo is called "Image title", my next step is to convert both text and images as one group to images so that way i can click right mouse to copy and paste over.

However, there is PHP code that allow me to convert into the image from text but I can't hardly figure out how can I convert from "image title" (demo) into the HTML!

Here is sample PHP code but I can't figure out how to combine it!

```
<?php
// Create a 100*30 image
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'Hello world!', $textcolor);

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Have any help me please how to convert this to images from jQuery code!

AM

Comment: What you could do is save your sample php code in say a file named "render_image.php", and then use a GET variable to pass the text to it. ie. `www.site.com/render_image.php?text=HelloWorld!` and then in the same code, change the hard-coded string into `$_GET['text']`. Here are some links that may help: http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_get.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: Yes i know about this part, i have tried that, it didnt works, any other idea!

Comment: i have tried this part, but the problem is that when i run this sample code with my jquery code, the result is only show unknown images and i did not go through jquery to select images and input the images title! they just by pass that code. and i can't hardly figure out what i missed.  can anyone help me please!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would probably be to just do:

```
// index.html
<img src="render_image.php?text=Hello World" />
```

and then:

```
// render_image.php
<?php
// Create a 100*30 image
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $_GET['text'], $textcolor);

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Using this with slight modifications to your javascript code should work.

More info on using the $_GET variable: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php